Prove or disprove: $P(A\cap B|C)=P(A\cap B)$ given $P(A|C)=P(A)$ and $P(B|C)=P(B)$.
Prove or disprove: $P(A\cap B|C)=P(A\cap B)$ given $P(A|C)=P(A)$ and $P(B|C)=P(B)$.
Since
\begin{align}
P(A \cap B|C)=P(B|A \cap C) P(A \cap C)/P(C)=P(B|A \cap C) P(A),
\end{align}
the statement is equivalent to: $P(B|A\cap C)=P(B|A)$ given $P(A|C)=P(A)$ and $P(B|C)=P(B)$.

Hint: look for a counterexample in a setting where there are two coin tosses and $A,B,C$ are various outcomes that could occur.

Something like $X={1,2,3,4,5,6}$ with uniform probability, $C={2,4,6}$, $A={2,3}$, $B={3,4}$ should work.

Thank you, Greg, Sassatelli and peterwhy. All comments answered my question.
